# How to split a string on multiple pattern using pythonic way (one liner)?

Tags: python

I am trying to extract file name from file pointer without extension. My file name is as follows:

`this site:time.list`,`this.list`,`this site:time_sec.list`, `that site:time_sec.list` and so on. Here required file name always precedes either whitespace or dot.

Currently I am doing this to get file from file name preceding white space and dot in file name.

```
search_term = os.path.basename(f.name).split(" ")[0]
```

and

```
search_term = os.path.basename(f.name).split(".")[0]
```

Expected file name output: `this`, `this`, `this`, `that`.

How can i combine above two into one liner kind and pythonic way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you splitting on a dot?

Comment: Case #2, perhaps, `re` module is probably a better bet here.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, to split the file-name string on dot.

Comment: But if you're already splitting on space, then what more do you need?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, read the question again.

Comment: @AChampion, how?

Comment: `re.split('[ .]', os.path.basename(f.name))[0]` ???

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Yes, regex would be the best way.

Comment: Thanks @Skycc, that worked like charm. Could you please post your this one liner simple answer for me to accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using regex as below,
`[ .]` will split either on a space or a dot char

```
re.split('[ .]', os.path.basename(f.name))[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you split on one and splitting on the other still returns something smaller, that's the one you want.  If not, what you get is what you got from the first split.  You don't need regex for this.

```
search_term = os.path.basename(f.name).split(" ")[0].split(".")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to get the first word at the beginning of the string:

```
import re

re.match(r"\w+", "this site:time_sec.list").group()
# 'this'

re.match(r"\w+", "this site:time.list").group()
# 'this'

re.match(r"\w+", "that site:time_sec.list").group()
# 'that'

re.match(r"\w+", "this.list").group()
# 'this'
```

try this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\w+")
pattern.match(os.path.basename(f.name)).group()
```

---

Make sure your filenames don't have whitespace inside when you rely on the assumption that a whitespace separates what you want to extract from the rest. It's much more likely to get unexpected results you didn't think up in advance if you rely on implicit rules like that instead of actually looking at the strings you want to extract and tailor explicit expressions to fit the content.

Comment: This will split on any character which isn't `\w` so semicolon, comma, dash, etc.  Maybe specifically extract `r'^[^ .]+'` to avoid this.

Comment: @tripleee Isn't this exactly what he wants? Just the filename?

Comment: The example is probably not representative of any real-world data.  If `this` or `that` could contain a dash, for example, you are extracting the wrong thing.

Comment: @tripleee I understand now what you mean, yes he would write something like `pattern = re.compile(r"[\w\\]+")` to catch  dashes. I think it's general the better approach to be explicit about what you search if possible.

Comment: Huh? No, being explicit about what you search means `pattern = re.compile(r'^[^ .]+')` like I wrote in a previous comment

Comment: @tripleee No he want's to extract the filename, not whitespace or dots. What if there are two whitespaces in the end?

Comment: The regular expression I posted extracts characters from the beginning of the string up until just before the first dot or space. It doesn't even examine the number of spaces near the end of the string.

Comment: Yes, but that's relies on what the search result is NOT, instead of explicitly on what it is, a bunch of word characters, dashes and whatever you explicitly specifiy it should be made of.